# Best way to populate a user defined object using the values of string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am reading two different csv files and populating data into two different objects. I am splitting each line of csv file based on regex(regex is different for two csv files) and populating the object using each data of that array which is obtained by splitting each line using regex as shown below:

```
public static <T> List<T> readCsv(String filePath, String type) {
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
        list = bufferedReader.lines().skip(1).map(line -> {
            T obj = null;
            String[] data = null;
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Student")) {
                data = line.split(",");
                ABC abc = new ABC();
                abc.setName(data[0]);
                abc.setRollNo(data[1]);
                abc.setMobileNo(data[2]);
                obj = (T)abc;
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
                data = line.split("\\|");
                XYZ xyz = new XYZ();s
                xyz.setName(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
                xyz.setCity(data[1]);
                xyz.setEmployer(data[2]);
                xyz.setDesignation(data[3]);
                obj = (T)xyz;
            }

            return obj;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());} catch(Exception e) {

    }}
```

csv files are as below:
i. csv file to populate ABC object:

```
Name,rollNo,mobileNo
Test1,1000,8888888888
Test2,1001,9999999990
```

ii. csv file to populate XYZ object

```
Name|City|Employer|Designation
Test1|City1|Emp1|SSE
Test2|City2|Emp2|
```

The issue is there can be a missing data for any of the above columns in the csv file as shown in the second csv file. In that case, I will get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.
Can anyone let me know what is the best way to populate the object using the data of the string array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other issue is `type == "Employee"` isn't going to work like you expect. `type.equals("Employee")` is how it should be written (assuming `type` can't be null).

Comment: Or `"Employee".equals(type)` if it can be null. There's also methods related to ignoring upper/lower case.

Comment: Or `Objects.equals("Employee", type)` if it can or can't be null.

Comment: You say that data could be missing for any of the columns, but would that mean even the pipe divider is missing? If so, could data from the 4th column technically be in the 3rd position, etc? If that's possible, I'm not sure how you could ever trust the data you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other mistakes you made and that were pointed out to you in the comments your actual problem is caused by `line.split("\\|")` calling `line.split("\\|", 0)` which discards the trailing empty String. You need to call it with `line.split("\\|", -1)` instead and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that one or more of the *last* values on any given CSV line may be empty.  In that case, you run into the fact that `String.split(String)` suppresses trailing empty strings.

Supposing that you can rely on all the fields in fact being *present*, even if empty, you can simply use the two-arg form of `split()`:

```
data = line.split(",", -1);
```

You can find details in [that method's API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-).

If you cannot be confident that the fields will be present at all, then you can force them to be by adding delimiters to the end of the input string:

```
data = (line + ",,").split(",", -1);
```

Since you only use the first values few values, any extra trailing values introduced by the extra delimiters would be ignored.